# Django object not saving even after "save" call

Tags: python, sql, database, django, sqlite

I'm really at a loss because this makes no sense at all. I call save/create an object, and it dosn't show up in the admin site. I even checked the SQLite database with a SQLite Viewer program, which again showed that the item had not been saved.

This is the code that saves the `Data` object:

```
        data = Data(represents=field, for_entry=entry, value="This can be anything")
        # field is a DataField db object and entry is a Entry db object (see model below and paragraph)
        print("B4", data) #<---- Shows that Data has not been assigned an ID/pk
        data.save()
        print("8ER: ", data) #<--- Shows that Data has been assigned an ID/pk
```

As you can see from my comments, I know that the Data object is assigned an ID after the `save` call, which I would think meant that it worked. No error is thrown anywhere. `field`, and `entry` are all both. Each one seems to be ok, as in they have the right IDs, were retrieved with `[table name].objects.get(id=...)`, and I can save/edit them and their saves change.

Even strange, this exact code in a function that is called right before this one works.

This is my model.py (I took out some functions to make it shorter):

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Entry', blank = True, null = True, default=None) #  The entry this subs. Is left blank for top level entries.
    id_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    visible = models.BooleanField()
    data_field = models.ForeignKey('DataField', default=1)  # The field that this entire entry falls under. REDUNDANT BUT NECISSARY

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)+ "-" + str(self.id_number) 

class DataField(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('DataField', related_name='parent field', null=True, blank=True, default=1)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    multiple_entries = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    DATA_TYPES = (('t', 'Text'), ('d', 'Date'), ('l', 'List'), ('o', 'Option'), ('b', 'Boolean'), ('f', 'Foreign Key'), ('r', 'Root'), ('bb', 'Branch'), ('i', 'Image'), ('ff', 'File'), ('h', 'Holder'), ('bt', 'Big Text'))  # A number means it is a foreign key. Should go off title.
    foreign_source = models.ForeignKey('DataField', null=True, blank=True) #  Points to DATA FIELD WHO'S MATCHING DATA WILL MAKE UP THE OPTIONS
    data_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=DATA_TYPES, default='t', null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    visibility = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + "-" + str(self.title)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, DataField):
            return False
        if self.data_type == 'h':
            return self.title == other.title
        return self.id == other.id


class Data(models.Model):
    represents = models.ForeignKey('DataField')
    for_entry = models.ForeignKey('Entry', null=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=1000000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.represents.title + "-" + str(self.for_entry.id) + "-" + str(self.value) + "-" + str(self.id)
```

It's possible that I'm missing something obvious, or maybe you need way more information than I can provide to fix it. If there is not enough information, please comment and request more info, or just list possible issues that could be happening.

Comment: Is AUTOCOMMIT set to false by chance and the other function is doing an explicit commit?

Comment: Please provide a code that you're executing i.e. the snippet where the save() method fails. It'd be easier if we could see what exactly parameters for save() are.

Comment: @pkacprzak Unfortunately, they're set in a completely different part of the program (that interacts with several other parts. So, probable 60+ lines of code). From every test I've been able to do, it seems that they are valid database objects of the DateField and Entry class. The last argument (the value) can be a basic string and it still will not work.

Comment: @Sid Thanks, but it isn't. I double checked just in case.

Comment: How do you know that it's not being saved. Because of the "value" field not reflecting the saved value?

Comment: @Sid I instantiate it and then save it, so it's a new object. It's not getting created.

Comment: My advise is to enable logging and check the log file as every SQL statements generated can be logged there. Then you can see how Django is attempting to save. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/

Comment: @Sid I'm not that well versed in SQL, but it seems that the statement is never being sent... why would that be?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Did you check the logs? What is the statement that is being generated? Are you saying it's not being generated or not being sent to the database?

Comment: @Sid It's not being generated! The last SQL statement is from when I got the ID of a field a couple lines before. It doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue doing a unit test and encountered an error where it appeared the save method wasn't working --> was as follows

```
p = MyModel.objects.get(pk=myparam)
self.assertEqual(p.my_attr, value) 
myfunc()  # Code that changed the same object p is referencing
self.assertEqual(p.my_attr, new_value)
```

The above failed even though I changed the object being referenced to the new value and then did .save() on the object.

To fix the issue, I had to reassign p to the MyModel object. My fixed code in the unit test looked something like this.

```
p = MyModel.objects.get(pk=myparam)
self.assertEqual(p.my_attr, value) 
myfunc()  # Code that changed the same object p is referencing
p = MyModel.objects.get(pk=myparam)
self.assertEqual(p.my_attr, new_value)
```

It appears to be an issue with the variable pointing to an old location in memory, but I only started programming 5 months ago so I'm in a little over my head :) I would really appreciate feedback if anyone can explain why this is happening as I'm still stumped.

If you REALLY don't think the save method is executing, you can do a sanity check by overwriting the save method and add a print statement. It might look similar to the following:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    attr = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        print('Did this attribute update? (attr):', self.attr)
        print('Save method executed!')
```

EDIT: Inline with the memory location theory, I made this simple example:

```
In [3]: a = 1
In [4]: b = a
In [5]: hex(id(a))
Out[5]: '0x100240280'
In [6]: hex(id(b))
Out[6]: '0x100240280'
In [7]: a = 2
In [8]: b
Out[8]: 1
In [9]: hex(id(a))
Out[9]: '0x1002402a0'
In [10]: hex(id(b))
Out[10]: '0x100240280'
```

Would still love to hear anyones thoughts.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. I solved it by assigned the object to a new variable, making my changes and saving the new variable:

```
    location = self.location  # self.location is set by other methods
    location.is_active = True
    location.save()
```

Answer (score 3):

Try a manual commit. I don't know what else to suggest.

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.commit_manually
def viewfunc(request):
    ...
    data.save()
    transaction.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I just ended up uninstalling and reinstalling django to a new vertualenv with the latest version of python (I WAS using python3.2). Then I copied over all of my code. I don't know why, but it worked. Maybe I messed something up in the settings file. Thanks again!

Comment: Hmm, I'm just glad it worked for you. Guess we'll never find out why it wasn't working...

Comment: I'm facing this issue in my python 3.2 based program - the save function acts as if it's been blocked by a firewall, I'm amazed cos other objects will get saved in the same method while a random one will be blocked. I believe this to be an error on this version of django but I'll just upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Use `django refresh_from_db()` function in the object you need to be updated.

Comment: Format your code and describe more so your answer be more clear

Comment: This is just for inline refresh so as to use a saved data nothing more.