# Django Rolling Back Instance Save

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have the following code:

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        data = self.request.POST
        email, password = data.get("email"), data.get("password1")
        usr = User.objects.create_user(username=self.student.reg_number, email=email, password=password)

        self.student.user = usr
        self.student.save()
```

The line where I'm creating a user instance works, when used alone, i.e without referencing/assigning the `usr` object to the student object. So its like the moment I assign it to the `student` instance, it disappers or maybe undoes/rolls back the save that was previously done on line 4.

What might be the cause of this? I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35053718/8224266) answer on a similar question but I did not understand the proposed solution.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the contents of `models.py`? It's unclear to me what the relationship between students and users is.

Comment: A `Student` has a `user` field which indicates the user account a student logs in with.